# JAVASCRIPT HELP - code not working

Tags: javascript

My code isn't working, can someone please tell me what the problem is? 
I'm guessing it's the for loop, but I cannot find the problem.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

username = prompt("Please enter a your username:");

for (var i = 0; i < username; i++) {

if(isFinite(username.charAt(i))) {
result = true;
document.write("The username consists of one or more numbers." + BR);
}
else {
result = false;
document.write("The username must consist of one or more numbers." + BR);
}
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, make sure you don't have any syntax errors.

Comment: You have to be more descriptive, what is it you want to gain from us ? you need to post with a question

Comment: When I enter the username, nothing pops up.

Comment: `i < username.length` is what you are looking for

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the output I can probably assume you just want to check if `username` consists of at least one number, actually: a digit.

```
// iterate over the input
for (var i = 0; i < username.length; i++) {
  // check if it is a number (not a digit but that's the same here)
  if (isFinite(username.charAt(i))) {
    result = true;
    // The requirement "one or more numbers" is fulfilled,
    // we can break out of the loop
    break;
  } 
  else {
    result = false;
  }
  // print something according to "result"
  if(result === true){
    document.write('The username consists of one or more numbers.');
  } else {
    document.write('The username must consist of one or more numbers.');
  }
}
```

You have to go over the full length of the string to find out if there's **no** number but not if you want to find out if there is **any** number in it.

Now, if you want to test if it consists of **only** digits you have to reword the requirements, they are a bit too ambiguous now.

Additional hints:

- you need to check the input, you *always* have to check user input!
- you need to be aware that JavaScript strings are UTF16. Rarely a problem but gets easily one if you iterate over JavaScript strings.
- `String.charAt()` returns a character, not a number. Don't rely on the automatic conversions in JavaScript, you way too easily shoot yourself in the foot if you rely on it but also if you don't, so be careful.
- please don't use `document.write`, use either the console if available or change the text-node of an HTML element.

With these points in mind you may get something like this:

```
// make a list of digits
var digits = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
// ask the user for a username
var username = prompt("Please enter a your username:");
// check input
if (username.length === 0) {
  console.log('no username given');
} else {
  for (var i = 0; i < username.length; i++) {
    // indexOf searches for the same type, that's why the digits above 
    // are strings with quotes around them
    if (digits.indexOf(username.charAt(i)) >= 0) {
      result = true;
      // The requirement "one or more numbers" is fullfilled,
      // we can break out of the loop
      break;
    } 
    else {
      result = false;
    }
  }
  // print something according to "result"
  if (result === true) {
    console.log('The username consists of one or more numbers.');
  } else {
    console.log('The username must consist of one or more numbers.');
  }
}
```

The above is one variation of many and could easily give rise to a heated discussion on some forums (not here! Of course not! ;-) ) but I hope it helps.

Comment: Two downvotes, no reason given. What am I supposed to do, delete an accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code:

1. In the for loop, use the length of the variable to establish the stop condition

   for (var i = 0; i < username.length; i++)
2. `BR` is not defined

Working code: http://jsfiddle.net/f643fr4w/

Comment: Now it just prints "The username consists of one or more numbers." a bunch of times. If the username is 8 letters, it will print that 8 times.

Comment: You did not specified a required behavior, so I just gave you the minimum for your code to "work" (run, actually). You must dedicate a litle more time editing your question, so it is clear to us what you need. Now that I think, I shouldn't gave you an answer...

Answer (score -1):

Use a regex for such shenanigans:

```
var username = prompt("username plz kk thx");
var result = /[0-9]/.test(username);
document.write("The username " + (result ? "consists" : "must consist") + " of one or more numbers");
```